# What to use to fill pipe gap behind cooking stove

Tags: pipe, gas, stove, gap, seal

We just pulled out our cooking stove and found two gaps:

1. A bigger gap around the gas line and wall
2. A smaller gap on the wooden floor to the right of the bigger wall gap

What would you recommend to seal this to prevent pest or insects later on?
Mindful this is a gas line and behind stove where temperature can get higher.

[image]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Did you find pests in it? Pests will make their own holes, once they are in your house. Neither hole increases your likelihood of a pest incursion.

Comment: I'd be tempted to just stuff some fiberglass insulation up in there.

Answer (score 1):

The gas pipe area is just a sloppy/lazy/not done drywall job - patch with drywall, drywall tape, and drywall joint compound. Perhaps a touch of caulking when done right around the pipe.

The floor I'd probably fill with thinset, since I have some sitting around and it is hard to chew. Be thinking mice, or their friends. Any other cement-like product would suit. If all you have handy is drywall joint compound, stuff it full of that.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate it!